# Favorite way to infuse sounds with other sounds or Infuse moments with manipulated sounds

Tags: design

How can you go about infusing sounds with other sounds?

For example if you want the sound of a baby crying to increase the emotional pull of a certain moment or ambience I usually use an Impulse Response but I've also added massive amounts of reverb to the baby sound and used it like that.  I think that the effectiveness of a crying baby is somewhat the timbre and somewhat the identifiability of the sound but to what extent can you break these types of rules?
I've also used Paul's Time stretch to stretch out certain timbres.

What other ways can you use tricks like these and colorize scenes with emotion?

Answer (score 1):

Only thing I can add is that you can get interesting results by using 'normal' sounds as impulse responses eg I made a long decaying impulse from a loop group of girls whispering, by then playing different winds (which share some frequency content with the impulse) the winds took on some of the whispering...

Comment: Thats exactly what I mean, Tim.  I think that its really interesting using IR responses.  I added a time sped up short kids laughing to a some chimes that were happy sounding and it made it even happier.

I sometimes question my technique here though because the reverb can make it sound eerie.